# Cleaning Values in R

Tags: r, regex, string, data-cleaning

How to remove roman numerals `I/II/III`, parentheses `()`, anything in parentheses `(xyz)`, dashes `-`, semi-colons `;`, and Grades `Grade 21` from the characters in this dataframe?

```
#Original dataframe
Jobs <- c("Social Worker I (Child Welfare Services), Grade 21", "Engineer I/II/III, Grade 19/22/25", "Legislative Attorney; Grade 32")
df <- data.frame(Jobs)
df
```

Dataframe to look like this:

```
#dataframe
Jobs <- c("Social Worker", "Engineer", "Legislative Attorney")
df1 <- data.frame(Jobs)
df1
```

Comment: Hi Jeremy. In your data, do you only have the mentioned 3 job titles or more?

Comment: There are more job titles but those three jobs summarize the cleaning for the rest of the data.

Comment: Do you have a list of all job titles. The issue is, when you delete `I` it could be that an `I` character of a job title can be deleted. This can be applied to all cleaning cases. When you have all Job titles already, you can search for them and clean for them in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to remove matching substrings:

```r
library(tidyverse)

Jobs <- c("Social Worker I (Child Welfare Services), Grade 21", "Engineer I/II/III, Grade 19/22/25", "Legislative Attorney; Grade 32")
df <- data.frame(Jobs)

df %>%
  mutate(Jobs = Jobs %>%
    str_remove_all("I|II|III|Grade [0-9/]+|[-;]") %>%
    str_remove_all("[/,]") %>%
    str_remove_all("[(][^(]+[)]") %>%
    str_trim())
#>                   Jobs
#> 1        Social Worker
#> 2             Engineer
#> 3 Legislative Attorney
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-05 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

I am not a regex expert, but I hope the following `gsub` option could help

```
> trimws(gsub("(\\b((I+)/?)+\\b)|\\(.*?\\)|[-;,]|(Grade\\s\\S+)", "", Jobs))
[1] "Social Worker"        "Engineer"             "Legislative Attorney"
```

Comment: "Not a regex expert" :)